# Simpson's Paradox, Combining data across confounding variable when few values are missing

Tags: missing-data, expectation-maximization, simpsons-paradox

The statistical analysis of experimental data that I have to perform could be described as follows. Three drug treatments $D_1$, $D_2$ and $D_3$ were tested across three groups $G_1$, $G_2$ and $G_3$. For each group and treatment combination $D_i, G_k$ the data are exposure (no of patients being treated with drug) and effect (ratio of no of patients recovered from treatment to treated).
I have to find a ordered list of treatments according to their effectiveness.

It requires combining the data taken from different groups. I know about Simpson's paradox and from the Bayesian belief networks (establishing the causal relationships) I know that groups (confounding or lurking variable) affect the exposure of the treatment and the effectiveness of the treatment, so I should use the partitioned data across different groups to come to any inference. The one way that I came across to remove this paradox is to break one of the relationships between the confounding variable and exposure or confounding variable and effectiveness. The relationship between the confounding variable and exposure could be broken if the exposure is same across groups or is proportional and that could be achieved through scaling exposure and effectiveness (multiplying by a factor that balances out the exposure across different groups). This works fine if I have all the data for each treatment, group combination.

But the data I have has some missing values: for a few $D_i, G_k$ I don't have their exposure and effectiveness. Should I use expectation maximization techniques here to find out the missing values and then use scaling while combining data? If I could how should I proceed to avoid getting spurious results?

The one assumption from the domain knowledge could be made that I could make here is that the groups should affect the effectiveness of every treatment the same way and the effect should be multiplicative,

i.e. effect of drug for a group $D_i, G_k$ = effect of drug $D_i \times$ effect on group $G_k$

What could be other ways to find the ordered list?